# What does “book” mean in the output of 'lscpu -p'?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture

On Linux, the `lscpu -p` command outputs lots of information about the CPU architecture. One of the columns is the "book number". What does "book" mean in this context?

**EDIT**: the documentation of `lscpu` refers to "book" as:

"The logical book number. A book can contain several sockets."

It is still unclear to me what this is actually saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `lscpu` [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lscpu)

```
NODE
    The logical NUMA node number. A node may contain several books. 
BOOK
    The logical book number. A book can contain several sockets. 
SOCKET
    The logical socket number. A socket can contain several cores. 
CORE
    The logical core number. A core can contain several CPUs. 
CPU
    The logical CPU number of a CPU as used by the Linux kernel.
```

Books are currently only present on the s390 architecture [...]. Books are logically between sockets and nodes. [Source](http://marc.info/?l=util-linux-ng&m=130986537002859&w=2)

A processor book is a modular card in IBM mainframes that contains processors, memory, and I/O connections. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_book)

Comment: What about the "book number"? The documentation does not specify what it really means. CPU/Core/Socket/Node... the meaning of these are clear to me.

Comment: It does ("BOOK: The logical book number. A book can contain several sockets."), but it is not much of an explanation. Furthermore, a quick Google didn't give any good results either. Good question, and I'd like to know the answer too!

Comment: OMG, I accidentially edit it away when I reversed the order...

Comment: Added the relevant part below by original answer.

Comment: Books are also used in some POWER systems, e.g., the [IBM Power 795 server](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/hardware/795/specs.html) can have (from table) "Processor books Up to eight" and up to 32 sockets.